# Mock MVC - Add Request Parameter to test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I am using spring 3.2 mock mvc to test my controller.My code is

```
       @Autowired
       private Client client;
    
       @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String initUserSearchForm(ModelMap modelMap) {
            User user = new User();
            modelMap.addAttribute("User", user);
            return "user";
        }
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/byName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
        public
        @ResponseBody
        String getUserByName(
           @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName,
           @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName,
           @ModelAttribute("userClientObject") UserClient userClient) {
            return client.getUserByName(userClient, firstName, lastName);
        }
```

and I wrote following test:

```
@Test public void testGetUserByName() throws Exception {
        String firstName = "Jack";
        String lastName = "s";       
        this.userClientObject = client.createClient();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/byName")
                .sessionAttr("userClientObject", this.userClientObject)
                .param("firstName", firstName)
                .param("lastName", lastName)               
        ).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].fn").value("Marge"));
}
```

what i get is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$5.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:546)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
```

Why this happens? Is it right way to pass the @RequestParam

Answer (score 159, accepted):

When i analyzed your code. I have also faced the same problem but my problem is if i give value for both first and last name means it is working fine. but when i give only one value means it says 400. anyway use the .andDo(print()) method to find out the error

```
public void testGetUserByName() throws Exception {
    String firstName = "Jack";
    String lastName = "s";       
    this.userClientObject = client.createClient();
    mockMvc.perform(get("/byName")
            .sessionAttr("userClientObject", this.userClientObject)
            .param("firstName", firstName)
            .param("lastName", lastName)               
    ).andDo(print())
     .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id").exists())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].fn").value("Marge"));
}
```

If your problem is `org.springframework.web.bind.missingservletrequestparameterexception` you have to change your code to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/byName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getUserByName(
        @RequestParam( value="firstName",required = false) String firstName,
        @RequestParam(value="lastName",required = false) String lastName, 
        @ModelAttribute("userClientObject") UserClient userClient)
    {

        return client.getUserByName(userClient, firstName, lastName);
    }
```

Comment: I wrote same code, But have problem with modelAttribute. please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427341/why-modelatribute-passed-as-null

Comment: Take a note, `print()` is a method of `MockMvcResultHandlers` class

Answer (score 23):

If anyone came to this question looking for ways to add multiple parameters at the same time (my case), you can use `.params` with a *MultivalueMap* instead of adding each `.param` :

```
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>()
requestParams.add("id", "1");
requestParams.add("name", "john");
requestParams.add("age", "30");

mockMvc.perform(get("my/endpoint").params(requestParams)).andExpect(status().isOk())
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ModelAttribute` is a Spring mapping of request parameters to a particular object type.  so your parameters might look like `userClient.username` and `userClient.firstName`, etc.  as MockMvc imitates a request from a browser, you'll need to pass in the parameters that Spring would use from a form to actually build the `UserClient` object.

(i think of ModelAttribute is kind of helper to construct an object from a bunch of fields that are going to come in from a form, but you may want to do some reading to get a better definition)

Comment: I used ModelAttribute before that was not a problem.I have confused with how to send @RequestParam