# Why ModelAtribute passed as null?

Tags: java, testing, spring-mvc, request, mockito

I developed next target class

```
class Person{
    public Person(){}
    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

next controller:

```
@Controller
        private static class SampleController {


                @RequestMapping(value="/path", method=RequestMethod.POST)
                public String path(@Valid @ModelAttribute("person") Person person, BindingResult result, Model model) {
                    model.addAttribute("name",person.getName()); 
                    System.out.println(person.getName());
                    return "view";
                }
        }
```

and next test:

```
public class ModelAssertionTests {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void setup() {

                SampleController controller = new SampleController("a string value", 3, new Person("a name"));

                this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
                                .defaultRequest(get("/"))
                                .alwaysExpect(status().isOk())
                                .build();
        }
        @Test
        public void testTest() throws Exception {
                Person person = new Person("name");
                mockMvc.perform(post("/path").sessionAttr("person", person));
        }
}
```

Switch on debug mode

at this line:

```
 mockMvc.perform(post("/path").sessionAttr("person", person));
```

I see that

[image]

when I go to controller method to:

```
 model.addAttribute("name",person.getName());
```

I see that

[image]

What the reason of it?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is because `sessionAttr("person", person)` in your mockMvc request sets `person` as a *session attribute*, while `@ModelAttribute` annotates *model attributes*.

To put session variable into the model (and therefore fix you problem), use `@SessionAttributes` annotation:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("person")
private static class SampleController {
    ...
}
```

Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args).

By the way, your Controller should be `public`, not `private static`.

Comment: You are right. But maybe exist other way. I think that it is bad way if test code affects on normal code

Comment: The other option is to send data using regular `.param()` method instead of `sessionAttr()`, but this also affects your Controller as you'll need to use `@RequestParam` instead od @ModelAttribute("person")`. Without knowing what do you want to achieve, it's hard to tell which solution is the best.

Comment: I guess that you just want to pass `person` as parameter to controller, then add person's name to model and return a view. If that's the case, you'll probably want to use solution from my previous comment.

Comment: @gstackoverflow. This is the correct way to set SessionAttribute.I did samething