# unit testing for spring mvc controller with Integer value as @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have the following controller which accept input as `@RequestParam`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchstatus", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Response fetchStatus(
        @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = true) Integer userId) {
    Response response = new Response();
    try {
        response.setResponse(service.fetchStatus(userId));
        response = (Response) Util.getResponse(
                response, ResponseCode.SUCCESS, FETCH_STATUS_SUCCESS,
                Message.SUCCESS);
    } catch (NullValueException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = (Response) Util.getResponse(
                response, ResponseCode.FAILED, e.getMessage(), Message.ERROR);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = (Response) Util.getResponse(
                response, ResponseCode.FAILED, e.getMessage(), Message.ERROR);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I need a unit test class for this and I am beginner with spring mvc. I don't know writing test classes with `@RequestParam` as input.

Any help will be appreciated ..

Comment: Do you want to write a UNIT or an INTEGRATION test. If it is a unit test, just call the method like any other method. If you want an integration test use the Spring MVC testing support (see reference guide).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock MVC - Add Request Parameter to test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972428/mock-mvc-add-request-parameter-to-test)

Comment: what if the inputted parameter is an integer. It's showing .param() needs parameter as String.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this issue. I just changed the url. Now it contains the parameter as below in test class:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/fetchstatus?userId=1").andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Strange, requestAttr() should work as well, if you set up everything correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) for testing Spring controllers.

```
@Test
public void testControllerWithMockMvc(){
  MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controllerInstance).build();
  mockMvc.perform(get("/fetchstatus").requestAttr("userId", 1))
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Also, it is possible to do it using pure JUnit, as long as you need to test only the logic inside your class

```
@Test
public void testControllerWithPureJUnit(){
  Controller controller = new Controller();
  //do some mocking if it's needed

  Response response = controller.fetchStatus(1);
  //asser the reponse from controller
}
```